# Create an Admin panel with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I went through a blog; 
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

I have already built the frontend of the whole site and now the client wants few features to be added in an admin section. I followed the 1st method but it didn't work for me except the very first page (i.e. set in routes.php as `$route['default_controller'] = "main";`).

The URL looks like `"http://localhost/myproject/admin/dashboard"` , yes it leads to a `404 page`.

I have fully followed the way you have described above (folder structure and setting 2 index files). Am i missing anything? Or it just doesn't work at all in my case?

Comment: the full block of code would help a lot

Comment: The problem is propably not your routing, but somewhere else. And creating a backend/admin panel to CI can be done with just a folder in the `controllers` folder called `admin` with a new `welcome.php` controller file.

Comment: @DamienPirsy ; that doesn't work either....but yeah http://localhost/myproject/dashboard works perfect.

Comment: is it an apache 404 page or codeigniter's (yellowish) 404 page?

Comment: @AnilSharma got solution?

Answer (score 1):

is your site so big that you need this ?
because if you dont know codeigniter, this adds a level of complexity thats not needed, also note that the howto is from 2009 and definately not using the latest codeigniter 2

I would rethink exactly what you need

if you have nothing working now, here is another howto link
http://andreytech.com/creating-crud-admin-panel-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank you John. You are right too, the tutor i followed was from 2009. Probably the things have changed in present version of CI. Could you please do me a favor by trying it out once?

Answer (score 0):

This would help you

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC

Wonderful package helps you to integrate CI in  modular structure .I've used this for one project. Great it will consider admin as a module ,also you can create blog,forum modules etc

Answer (score 0):

i am also following the same blog there. 
"You'll need to set a $route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard'; to get example.com/admin worksing but thats easy enough."
doing above, when i point to admin it shows the dashboard view.